# display and save a local image into database in react js

Tags: reactjs, postgresql

I'am developing a blog website using react.js  where users can post and comment ...
so we know that a user can comment with an image ,and let's say he want to upload a local image that stored in his machine,i want to display that image as a comment and save it into postgres database which i'am using for that.
**My question** is what are the steps that i should follow to achieve my purpose,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to do in simple steps, you can save the image to base64, its just string representation of an image. So it can be saved in DB directly and when you have to show it just decode the string and display it accordingly.
`References :-`

> 1. https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64#readme
> 2. https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-encode-and-decode-strings-with-base64-in-javascript

Alternatively, what you can do when user selects an image, then upload that image to your server and get the path to that(multipart file upload) and from path you can show it where you want to show.
`References :-`

> [how to send a multipart/form-data from React.js with an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168659/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-from-react-js-with-an-image)

I hope it helps, Thanks :)

Comment: what do you think if i just create object url for image and save that url into database and once i want that image i get just the url ?

Comment: Yes, create the url and save it and for showing just show it as url. It will works.

Comment: upvote the answer if somehow i have helped you... Thanks

Comment: i can't because of this Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. my reputation less than 15 u understand me by the way can you give me ur facebook to contact you if you don't mind thanks.

Comment: Yeah happy to share my knowledge and for the community, nice talking with you